# Is the Cantor set countable dense homogeneous in pairs?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups

I know that the Cantor set is countable dense homogeneous. My question is: if A,B,C,D are countable dense subsets of the Cantor set such that the pairs A and B and C and D are disjoint, there exists a homeomorphism f of the Cantor set such that f(A) = C and f(B) = D?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes, unless I'm missing something, via a back-and-forth argument.

For simplicity I'll view the Cantor set as the set of infinite binary sequences, $2^\omega$, and think of this as the set of paths through the infinite binary tree $2^{<\omega}$.

Any rooted-tree automorphism $\alpha$ of $2^{<\omega}$ induces an autohomeomorphism $h_\alpha$ of $2^\omega$. Call the autohomeomorphisms so induced the *standard* ones.

Let $A\cup B=X$, $C\cup D=Y$. Call a finite partial bijection $p: X\rightarrow Y$ *good* if

- $p: A\rightarrow C$, $p: B\rightarrow D$, and
- There is some standard autohomemorphism $h$ of $2^\omega$ such that $p\prec h$.

Then:

- The empty map is good.
- **(Forth)** For any good map $p$ and any $x\in X$, there is some $y\in Y$ such that $p\cup\{(x, y)\}$ is again good.
- **(Back)** For any good map $p$ and any $y\in Y$, there is some $x\in X$ such that $p\cup\{(x, y)\}$ is again good.

*Why? Well, the first point is trivial, and the second and third are true for the same reason, so let's talk about the **forth** part. Think of a good map $p$ as labelling each node of $2^{<\omega}$ which is an initial segment of an element of the domain of $p$, **or the immediate successor of such an initial segment**, with either "$0$" or "$1$". For instance, if $p$ is the map which sends $00000...$ to $10101010...$ and does nothing else, then $p$ would label $0$ with $1$, $00$ with $0$, $000$ with $1$, $0000$ with $0$, and so on; and also labels $1$ with $0$ (because that's forced by where $p$ sends $0$), but would not label $11$ anything (because that's not forced by $p$ at all). Now, if $x\in 2^\omega\setminus dom(p)$, then at some point $x$ "leaves the labelled part" of $2^{<\omega}$. As soon as that happens, we're free to label the remaining nodes of $x$ however we like; so, just pick some appropriate element of $Y$ that hasn't been used yet, and go!*

This lets us build, via the usual back-and-forth method, a bijection $B: X\rightarrow Y$ such that every finite submap of $B$ is good.

Now consider the map $$b: 2^{<\omega}\rightarrow 2^{<\omega}: \sigma\mapsto \tau\iff \exists \sigma\prec x\in X, p\prec B(x\in dom(p), p(x)\upharpoonright\vert\sigma\vert=\tau).$$ This is a rooted-tree automorphism of $2^{<\omega}$, and so induces a standard autohomeomorphism $h_b$ of $2^\omega$. And it's easy to check that $h_b$ extends $B$.

Comment: Nice! What you call "standard" homeomorphisms are the isometries for any natural ultrametric on the boundary (for instance, the one for which the distance between $x,y$ is $2^{-n}$ where $n$ is the height at which the paths from the root to $x,y$ fork. If I understand correctly, the homegeneity property actually holds for the group of isometries.

Comment: Very interesting this proof. I just didn't understand two things: 1) The definition of b. What do you mean by $\sigma \prec x$ and $p(x) \upharpoonright |\sigma|$? 2) Where do you used the density of the sets? One more thing: do you have a reference for this theorem (and related ones)? Thank you very much. It helped a lot.

Comment: @LucasHenrique "$\sigma\prec x$" means that $\sigma$ - a finite binary string - is an initial segment of $x$ - an infinite binary string. E.g. "$000$"$\prec$"$000000000000...$". Meanwhile, "$\tau\upharpoonright n$" - for a finite binary string $\tau$ and a natural number $n$ - means "the first $n$ bits of $\tau$"; e.g. $\tau\upharpoonright 0$ is the empty string, and $0101\upharpoonright 2=01$. Remember that $p(x)$ is a string, and $\vert\sigma\vert$ is the length of $\sigma$, hence a number. (cont'd)

Comment: Density is used in showing the Forth and Back properties. For the Forth property, this occurs at the last line of the italicized paragraph: "pick some appropriate element of $Y$ that hasn't been used yet". An appropriate element $y$ of $Y$ needs to be in the "right part" of $Y$: if $x\in A$, we need $y\in C$, and if $x\in B$ we need $y\in D$. In order to guarantee that such a $y$ exists, we need that both $C$ and $D$ are dense. Similarly, to show the Back property, we need that both $A$ and $B$ are dense. (cont'd)

Comment: I do not know a reference for this result. I believe, however, that the machinery of Fraisse limits can provide a relevant metatheorem; see e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.1683.pdf). Now I haven't actually read this paper, so I can't really vouch for it, but it looks good and relevant. Incidentally, it does *not* (so far as I know) contain this theorem on the nose, but I believe that the general theorems of the paper should work here.

Comment: I thought it was a classical result, like the countable densely homogeneous one. I need a reference for this theorem to my masters thesis. If I'm not able to find one, I would like to use your proof if you don't mind (with a special thanks attached, for sure).

Comment: @LucasHenrique Not at all, I'm flattered! However, I don't *know* that it's not explicitly stated elsewhere, or an immediate consequence of a known theorem (in fact I kind of suspect that it is). So if you *do* cite me, I would be very careful to say explicitly that this fact may have already been proved elsewhere but that you don't have a specific reference (in particular I don't want to be cited as having claimed that this was original). Also, I'd ask around your department - if this is a known fact, then probably one of the topologists around knows about it.

Comment: I could say you showed me that. In a fact, that's the truth. I don't work directly with topology (maybe some day), I work with geometric group theory, so I do not have access to the big picture of the development of the area. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Oh, definitely I'm fine if you say I showed you this; but I think it would be good form to state explicitly that there may be another reference that exists, but which you haven't found (I did that plenty of times in my Ph.D. thesis, it's fine to admit that you're not sure about original attribution as long as you gave it a serious try; e.g. in my case, there's lots of facts in my field that it's really hard to tell who proved them, or when, or in what context). Re: topologists, as long as there is one in your department, you can always ask them even though you don't do topology.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no topologist on my department. But I'll talk with my advisor. He should know where to search.